# Como obtener una variable enviada desde el servidor

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Mi código inicia así

res.render("index", {message: "Hello"});

La pregunta es como obtener esa variable message en codigo javascript.

Uso nodejs como servidor.
Para servir la plantilla uso pug. sucesor de jade.

Answer (score 0):

En el teplate PUG accedés a la variable mediante la interpolación, `#{nombreDeLaVariable}`. Por ejemplo:

```
html
   body
       h1 Hello World!
          p This is the message: #{message}
```

Comment: Pero quiero hacer uso de ella con javascript.

Comment: Lo he resulta practicamente así                           
script(type='text/javascript').
      const message = !{JSON.stringify(message)}
     alert(message);